# What does the parameter 'p' mean in a function of the sketch-rnn p5.js code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, user-interface, p5.js

I didn't see any code in the repo defines the **p** variable, so I am not sure what does that mean. Why does the function need the parameter 'p' and what does it mean?

The abstract structure of the code looks like this:

```
const sketch = function(p) {
...
p.setup = function(){...}
p.mousePressed = function () {...}
p.mouseReleased = function () {...}
p.mouseDragged = function () {...}
p.draw = function() {...}
...
}
...
new p5(sketch, 'sketch');
```

[Source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/magenta-js/blob/master/sketch/demos/interactive_predict.js#L27)

Comment: Take a look at this example: https://p5js.org/examples/instance-mode-instantiation.html When you use instance mode the p5js instance is passed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p` is the variable passed into the sketch function when it is invoked.